# why does MySQL Connector claim there is already an open DataReader when there isn't?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm using the .NET Connector to access a MySQL database from my C# program.  All my queries are done with MySqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader, with the IAsyncResults held in a list so I can check them periodically and invoke appropriate callbacks whenever they finish, fetching the data via MySqlCommand.EndExecuteReader.  I am careful never to hold one of these readers open while attempting to read results from something else.

This mostly works fine.  But I find that if I start two queries at the same time, then I get the dreaded **MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first** exception in EndExecuteReader.  And this is happening the *first* time I invoke EndExecuteReader.  So the error message is full of baloney; there is no other open DataReader at that point, unless the connector has somehow opened one behind the scenes without me calling EndExecuteReader.  So what's going on?

Here's my update loop, including copious logging:

```
    for (int i=queries.Count-1; i>=0; i--) {
        Debug.Log("Checking query: " + queries[i].command.CommandText);
        if (!queries[i].operation.IsCompleted) continue;
        var q = queries[i];
        queries.RemoveAt(i);
        Debug.Log("Finished, opening Reader for " + q.command.CommandText);
        using (var reader = q.command.EndExecuteReader(q.operation)) {
            try {
                q.callback(reader, null);
            } catch (System.Exception ex) {
                Logging.LogError("Exception while processing: " + q.command.CommandText);
                Logging.LogError(ex.ToString());
                q.callback(null, ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("And done with callback for: " + q.command.CommandText);
    }
```

And here's the log:

[image: Screen shot of resulting log messages]

As you can see, I start both queries in rapid succession.  (This is the first thing my program does after opening the DB connection, just to pin down what's happening.)  Then the first one I check says it's done, so I call EndExecuteReader on it, and boom -- already it claims there's another open one.  This happens immediately, before it even gets to my callback method.  How can that be?

Is it not valid to have two open queries at once, even if I only call EndExecuteReader on one at a time?

Comment: Please enable STRICT ON , that is bad code.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: var q is an object not a mysqlcomand i am wondering why this gives you no error

Comment: "I get the dreaded ... exception in EndExecuteReader" In the APM pattern (which you're using), the `EndX` method throws any exceptions that occurred during the asynchronous operation, so this is completely expected. The exception message was true at the time the exception happened, not necessarily when it was thrown to your code.

Comment: @nbk, yes, q is an object that contains a MySQLCommand as a field.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger OK, so it sounds like the Reader opens as soon as the query begins, rather than when you call EndExecuteReader.  That would explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run two queries concurrently, you *must* have two Connection objects. Why? Each Connection can only handle one query at a time. It looks like your code got into some kind of race condition where some of your concurrent queries worked and then a pair of them collided and failed.

At any rate your system will be more resilient in production if you can keep your startup sequences simple. If I were you I'd run one query after another rather than trying to run them all at once. (Obvs if that causes real performance problems you'll have to run them concurrently. But keep it simple until you need it to be complex.)

Comment: Well that does seem to fit observations, but is this limitation documented anywhere?  I'd sleep better if I could point to the docs this refactoring depends on.  All I've been able to find is that you can't have two Reader objects open at once, but at this point I don't (despite the claim in the exception text).

Comment: It's documented for MySqlConnector (alternative MySQL ADO.NET library): https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/connection-reuse/

Comment: @JoeStrout Additionally, https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ provides _actual_ async I/O via the new `ExecuteReaderAsync` APIs (that return `Task` and are much easier to use than `Begin`/`EndExecuteReader`). I would strongly recommend switching.